# Reversing Text in a specific way

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to reverse a Rubik's Cube algorithm (you don't need to know anything about the rubik's cube don't worry). E.g. R U R' U'

The rule for reversing is to write it in reverse: U' R' U R
Then apply the ' (prime) operator. Now it is: U R U' R'

So every letter with a ' now doesn't have one, and those that didn't now do.

Another example: (R' F R F')->(F' R F R')->(F R' F' R)

I have tried reversing the text by using TEXTJOIN(), it is a bit weird but it does the job, but applying that prime operator is something else man.

**EDIT**: Additionally for algorithms with brackets, like: (R U R' U') (R' F R F'), the brackets can be ignored if necessary.

Comment: Are you able to share more sample data with possible variations and expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution, also using `TEXTJOIN`. This assumes that there are 4 elements in a string - you can adjust the inline array constant as required, see `{3,2,1,0}`.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",255)),1+255*{3,2,1,0},255))&"'"),"''","")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: When released one can use SORT and SEQUENCE with the LEN()-LEN() I have to adjust it for no matter the length: `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),1+99*(SORT(SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1),,-1)-1),99))&"'"),"''","")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Apparently that function isn't valid. The error is pointing to the SORT bit.

Comment: @Simplex1 true, it also fails on the `SORT` bit for me. How about the formula that I posted, does it work for you?

Comment: As Scott mentioned, `SORT` and `SEQUENCE` functions are only available for Office Insiders. I'm curious to test Scott's function once it is being released to all Office 365 subscribers. Here's Scott's formula for those who do not yet have access to the new functions: `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),1+99*(sort),99))&"'"),"''","")` (array formula), where: `sort` = `=TRANSPOSE(LARGE(sequence,sequence)-1)` and `sequence` = `=ROW(INDEX(Sheet9!$A:$A,1,1):INDEX(Sheet9!$A:$A,LEN(Sheet9!$A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet9!$A1," ",""))+1,1))`

Comment: Love your idea of adding `'` to the string and then replace `""` with blank! You can replace `{3,2,1,0}` within your formula with `(LARGE(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'",""))/2+1))),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'",""))/2+1))))-1)` which will make the formula more universal, and the formula will become an **array formula**.

Comment: Thanks @TerryW, glad you liked it - also thanks for an updated formula, this is useful!

Answer (score 1):

Use this array version of TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(RIGHT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)-ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)))*99+1,99)))="'",LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)-ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)))*99+1,99))),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)-ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)))*99+1,99))&"'"))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.

[image]